# Normal subgroups statement

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading an algebra book and when the (second) Isomorphism theorem was derived, the following was stated:

Let $N\subset H\subset G$ where $N,H,G$ are groups and $H$ is a normal subgroup in $G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup in $G$. It then follows, that $N$ is a normal subgroup in $H$.

This can not always be true, can it?

Comment: Yes, it is true: a normal subgroup of a group $\;G\;$ is always normal in **any** subgroup of $\;G\;$ containing it.

Comment: Could you prove it for me? Thank you!

Comment: @EpsilonDelta If $h\in H$ and $x\in N$, then $hxh^{-1}\in N$ (a special case of $N$ being normal in $G$).

Comment: What definition for normal subgroups are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $N\subseteq H\subseteq G$ and that $N$ and $H$ are normal in $G$.  Now, there are several common definitions for normality, for example, one could use one of:

- For all $g\in G$, $gHg^{-1}=H$.
- For all $g\in G$, $gH=Hg$.

Either way, the theorem follows.  Let's try the second definition:

We want to prove that for all $h\in H$, $hN=Nh$.  Since $H\subseteq G$, if $h\in H$, then $h\in G$, so since $N$ is normal in $G$, $hN=Nh$.  This proves that $N$ is normal in $H$.

Answer (score 4):

It is always true. 
If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ then $gNg^{-1}=N$ for all$ g $ in $G$. In particular to all $g$ in $H$. This is equivalent to N being a normal subgroup